# How can I fix this error : Python Error ""ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4) into shape (1000)""

Tags: deep-learning, keras, feature-extraction, transfer-learning

I have the following python code:

```
from keras.applications import InceptionResNetV2
conv_base=InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet',
                            include_top=False,
                            input_shape=(150,150,3))
#conv_base.summary ()
# Extract features
import os, shutil
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
batch_size = 16

def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 3, 3, 1536))  # Must be equal to the output of the convolutional base
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count))
    # Preprocess data
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory,
                                            target_size=(150,150,),
                                            batch_size = batch_size,
                                            shuffle=False,
                                            class_mode='categorical')
    # Pass data through convolutional base
    i = 0
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
        labels[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            break
    return features, labels

train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_dir, 384)  # Agree with our small dataset size
validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(validation_dir, 80)
test_features, test_labels = extract_features(test_dir, 86)
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-31-6bdd0a78c5f7>", line 26, in <module>
    train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_dir, 384)

  File "<ipython-input-31-6bdd0a78c5f7>", line 20, in extract_features
    labels[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from the shape (16,4) into shape (16)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data generator retrieves your labels as `categorical` and based on the error, I assume you have `4` classes. However, in your `extract_features` function, you are first initializing a labels array of `shape=(sample_count)` instead of `shape=(sample_count, 4)`. In your `for` loop, you are getting a `labels_batch` from the generator which apparently has a shape of `(16, 4)` and you are trying to save it as part of your initialized `labels` array which has a shape of `(sample_count)` instead of `(sample_count, 4)` and that's why it complains.

**In short**, you should change:

```
labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count))
```

to:

```
labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 4))
```